# Import existing VMware machines into VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, vmware, osx-yosemite, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to load some existing VMware disk stored in an external USB3 HD into VMware Fusion for Mac OS X but no matter how i do it but Mac OS X always copy the imported vmware machine into the local hard drive.

What i did is, download the following `https://github.com/xdissent/ievms` VMware machines and stored them into an external USB3 hard drive. Then i've managed to import them into VMware Workstation on some GNU/Linux machines with no issues. Now i'm trying to import them into VMware Fusion on a Mac OS X machine by going to `More options` -> `Create a custom virtual machine` -> `Choose OS: Windows 7` -> `Use an existing disk` -> `Choose virtual disk` and there i select the vmk anf then no matter if i select `Share this virtual disk...` or `Take this disk away` but Mac OS X copies the vmware disk from the external USB into the local hard drive which is clearly not what i' looking for.

So I'm trying to import an existing vmware disk without moving or copying it form the external USB into the local hard drive, but i'm doing something wrong. Any tip?

Thanks!!

Comment: StackOverflow's focus is programming - you may have better luck asking this on one of the other [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) sites like [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Have you tried just double clicking the .vmx?